# UIImage to String and String to UIImage in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uiimage, base64, nsuserdefaults

I add name of the user and photo user to `UserDefaults` array then send this array to my site + insert this array in another `ViewController`

Code to save:

```
 let imageSaveData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.profileUserPhotoImage.image!, 1.0) as NSData?    
 let base64String = imageSaveData?.base64EncodedString()
    let userNameAdnPhoto = ["name": self.userNameLabel.text, "image": base64String] as? [String: String]
    var userArrayToUDef = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "userInfo") as? [[String: String]]
```

In another `ViewController` I don't know how to get from `UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "userInfo")` image to `UIImageView` in `ViewController`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

String image convert in to UIImage

**String to UIImage**

```
yourString.toImage() // it will convert String  to UIImage

extension String {
    func toImage() -> UIImage? {
        if let data = Data(base64Encoded: self, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters){
            return UIImage(data: data)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Convert UIImage to string then this is used

**UIImage to String**

```
yourImage.toPngString() // it will convert UIImage to string

extension UIImage {
    func toPngString() -> String? {
        let data = self.pngData()
        return data?.base64EncodedString(options: .endLineWithLineFeed)
    }
  
    func toJpegString(compressionQuality cq: CGFloat) -> String? {
        let data = self.jpegData(compressionQuality: cq)
        return data?.base64EncodedString(options: .endLineWithLineFeed)
    }
}
```

Comment: In another ViewController I have  `@IBOutlet weak var userPhotoImage: UIImageView!`   do I do the right thing . -  userPhotoImage.image = toImage    ?

Comment: this code conver uiimage to string and string to UIimage

Comment: frist of all get string in userdefault after convert in to uiimage

Comment: toImage() doesn't work with unicode flags?

Answer (score 2):

This function is just for string to UIImage.

```
  extension String {

        func stringToImage(_ handler: @escaping ((UIImage?)->())) {
            if let url = URL(string: self) {
                URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                    if let data = data {
                        let image = UIImage(data: data)
                        handler(image)
                    }
                }.resume()
            }
        }
    }
```

use this function as,

```
            yourString.stringToImage {(image) in
              self.yourPhoto.image = image
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, "UIImagePNGRepresentation" method is updated to "pngData()" method.

If you want to convert UIImage to String, you can use the following lines:

```
extension UIImage {
    func toString() -> String? {

        let pngData = self.pngData()

        //let jpegData = self.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75)

        return pngData?.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is from swift playgrounds shapes:

```
extension String {
/// Returns a SPCScene.Image from a string. Use to generate an image, based on an emoji string.
func image() -> UIImage {
    let size = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    UIColor.clear.set()
    let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
    UIRectFill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
    (self as AnyObject).draw(in: rect, withAttributes: [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 70)])
    if let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
        
    } else {
        return UIImage()
    }
}
}
```

It 100% Works